# Help for PWM circuit for 12 volts DC up to 1.3 A

Tags: pwm

Is there a way to do a fairly simple PWM circuit that will handle 12 volts DC up to 1.3 Amps?
The 555 timers appear to fall in the 600 mA to 900 mA max power dissipation range.

Attached is the basic diagram that I have been working with.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: why would you need all that current in the 555? That circuit is fine, you are just missing the protection diode across the motor terminals.

Answer (score 1):

The IRFZ46N in the circuit is rated to 53A, and the 555 should have enough drive to turn it on and off. It is also fully avalanche rated (at 55V), but to be safe you may want to do as Vladimir said and add a flyback diode backwards across the motor.